# iMac Workstation

Tags: imac, daw, workstation

Does anyone do any heavy sound design on an iMac?  Just curious.  I was looking to purchase one for the home but I'm not too keen on its expandability (surround sound) and am wondering a bit about its performance.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've got an i7 at the studio, lots of heavy sound work done on it.  Set up with a 5.1 Blue Sky Media Desk system for surround work; it is a beast, tons of power.  Don't know what you mean by its expandability re surround work, that's dependent on your audio i/o.  We run audio thru a Steinberg MR816 via a FW800 to 400 converter and use a Euphonix MC Pro for a controller.

John.

Comment: I was thinking Pro Tools (HD) surround but I guess I could get the production toolkit and use a different interface, huh?

Comment: Well I guess "it is a beast" is more or less what I was looking for to push forward with this purchase.  Unless anyone else is getting issues with running verbs and large plug-in chains this simple question and answer is closed for me.

Thanks, John!

- Mike

Answer (score 1):

i currently do all sound design and arranging mixing and music production on my Macbook (not the new one with unibody) and it still works like a charm! even with 30 channels of audio / midi with instruments and at least 2-3 plugins at each channel running!

Macbook with 2.2 cpu with 2gb ram and 160gb HD at 5200rpm and M-Audio Fast track Pro, this setup keeps me running really good for 3-4 years now so i guess a new iMac will be more than enough for you. I forgot to mention i run Logic 9

Comment: Same here. White Macbook on the go, and a new mini in the studio. The new mini is especially great for the studio. Tiny, fast and dead silent. And I use my older mini as a node in Logic. :)